# How to spatially join attributes of a polygon closest/nearest to a point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

this seems like it should be a simple task but so far I've not had any luck. I have a points shapefile (showing where manholes are on public roads), and a polygon shapefile showing where building foot prints are. I want to take the attributes of the closest building footprint polygon to a manhole point - using a nearest distance algorithm. Is there any simple way to achieve this in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is [refFunctions](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin, which will add `geomnearest()` function to your `Field Calculator`.

Then open the attribute table of your `manhole` point layer and create a new field with an expression `geomnearest('buildings', 'owner')` (if the layer name of your buildings is `buildings` and you want to extract its `owner` field. (Please note the single quotation marks, not double).

[image]

It will take the `owner` field and add the information to your `manhole` point layer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kazuhito! Your steps solved the issue perfectly. Appreciate the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple tool to do the task, you could consider the NNJoin plugin.  For each feature in the input layer (point, line, polygon), it finds the closest feature in the join layer (point, line, polygon). The resulting layer will for each input feature contain the distance to the closest join feature in addition to all the attributes of the input feature and the join feature.